# Mongoose query doesn´t return geometry property of GeoJSON

Tags: node.js, mongoose, leaflet, gis, geojson

Given the following document in my DB:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c03b36d13032cc192d33f84"),
    "type" : "Feature",
    "properties" : {
        "name" : "point 1",
        "amenity" : "test",
        "popupContent" : "test"
    },
    "geometry" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
           [ -3.68814468383789, 
            40.5248912033234]
        ]
    }
}
```

And given the following mongoose query:

```
function findVertex(req,res){
    Vertex2.find({"_id":"5c03b36d13032cc192d33f84"}, function(err,obj) {
        if(err){
            res.status(500).send(error);
        }else{
            var geoJson=obj[0];

            console.log(geoJson)
            res.status(200).send(geoJson);
        }

    })
}
```

What I receive is:

```
{ properties: { name: 'point 1', amenity: 'test', popupContent: 'test' },
  _id: 5c03b36d13032cc192d33f84,
  type: 'Feature' }
```

Why geometry is not in the response? If I do the same query in robomongo I have the object with the coordinates.

Comment: What is your mongoose and mongodb versions?

Answer (score 0):

Base of [mongoDb GeoJSON object documnet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/geojson/#point) your `point` geometry structure is incorrect, `coordinates` must be an array with 2 element, not an array that contain another array

Comment: That´s true, I have made a mistake and I should have typed multipoint, as I want to add more points to the feature, so it should be arrays into an array, anyway, it doesn´t work

Answer (score 0):

At the end I have fixed it changing the model schema.

Initially I had this:

```
 _id:String,
type:String,
properties:{
    name:String,
    amenity:String,
    popupContent:String
},
geometry:{
    type:String,
    coordinates:[]
}
```

Now I have this:

```
type:String,
    properties:{
        name:String,
        amenity:String,
        popupContent:String
    },
    geometry:{
        type: {type: String, default: 'MultiPoint'},
        coordinates: {type: []}
    }
```

And I have the desired object in return:

```
{"properties":{"name":"Coors Field","amenity":"Baseball Stadium","popupContent":"This is where the Rockies play!"},"geometry":{"type":"MultiPoint","coordinates":[[-3.68814468383789,40.5248912033234],[-3.70814468383789,40.5248912033234],[-3.68230819702148,40.5074040815359]]},"_id":"5c03a3da82822133f0406667","type":"Feature","__v":0}
```